# How to pass multiple image input-streams to im4java?

Tags: java, imagemagick, im4java

I am constructing a PSD with multiple layers using imagemagick. That works for me using the CLI command `convert 1.png 1.png 2.png test.psd`. (the extra 1.png is there because the first layer of a PSD is the flattened result of all layers)

I want to do it using im4java, without actually saving the images to the disk (using InputStream). That should be possible with an input [Pipe](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/docs/dev-guide.html#piping) initialized with an InputStream. However, it only works for me with **one input image**. If I have several, I don't know how to pass them all as input to the process' stdin.

I tried concatenating my image input streams using the `java.io.SequenceInputStream`, but this result in an error:

> org.im4java.core.CommandException: convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.

My code:

```
FileInputStream imageStream1 = new FileInputStream("1.png");
FileInputStream imageStream2 = new FileInputStream("2.png");
InputStream concatStreams = new SequenceInputStream(imageStream1, imageStream2);

IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
// "-" means to read the image from stdin
op.addImage("-"); // the first, "dummy" image
op.addImage("-"); // 1.png
op.addImage("-"); // 2.png

// output in PSD format to stdout
op.addImage("psd:-");

ConvertCmd cmd = new ConvertCmd();

Pipe pipeIn = new Pipe(concatStreams, null);
cmd.setInputProvider(pipeIn);

// omitted cmd.setOutputConsumer code

cmd.run(op);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but I ended up here from a google search so I thought it might be worth answering.

I solved it by loading the input as java.awt.image.BufferedImage instead of streams.

```
BufferedImage image1 = ImageIO.read("1.png");
BufferedImage image2 = ImageIO.read("2.png");

IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
// No argument means to use images given in cmd.run. 
// These can be either BufferedImage instances or Strings with the path to files.
op.addImage(); // the first, "dummy" image
op.addImage(); // 1.png
op.addImage(); // 2.png

// output in PSD format to stdout
op.addImage("psd:-");

ConvertCmd cmd = new ConvertCmd();

// omitted cmd.setOutputConsumer code

cmd.run(op, image1, image1, image2);
// for files directly: 
// cmd.run(op, "1.png", "1.png", "2.png");
```

Note that the output can still be piped to whatever you want.